# Blank screen after booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

On booting my Ubuntu System I see an Ubuntu startup symbol , after that the screen goes blank like it's going to boot up then it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing ctrl+alt+f1 after you get to the black screen. If that works you are at least able to boot into a command line of Ubuntu and you can work from there.